# Visual Studio "Setup Blocked" error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install a new version of Visual Studio, but it shows this "Setup Blocked" error and tells me to reboot the computer but that doesn't help. I had accidentally deleted all the files of VS instead of uninstalling it, I guess that's why this is happening. I have shown the last few logs, could someone please tell me how to uninstall this properly (it's still installed in the system)?

```
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i101: Detected package: iisexpress_msp_x86_en_us_1060, state: Absent, cached: None
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i101: Detected package: vwd_finalizer, state: Present, cached: Complete
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'RelatedBundleType_Patch' to value 2
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (WindowsBuildNumber < 9600)' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 0' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to true.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (IEsvcVersionExists) OR (IEsvcVersion < v10.0)' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT < v6.2) AND ((NetworkAvailable = 0) OR (DisableRootAutoUpdate = 1)) AND NOT ((MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011AuthRootExists) AND (MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010AuthRootExists))' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.31101)' evaluates to false.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: SystemRebootPendingBlock : The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue. Please restart the computer and run setup again.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[35FC:364C][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[35FC:3600][2015-10-16T21:46:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: As this is a general windows issue, and not specifically programming, you may get better assistance on this at superuser or serverfault. The problem you have is with another program installation that didn't complete successfully. Take a look at your system's registry key values for the keys defined at this page(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164360%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  The SystemRebootPendingBlock is coming from the the first key. Any information in the second key may help you figure out what program is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was able to solve the problem after going to the link you mentioned. :)